# AngularJS Directives with jQuery Key Bindings not Properly Loading Bindings When URL Changed via HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

Title says it all. I'm using AngularJS with jQuery key bindings inside directives. New directives are called on different pages with different keyboard layouts.

For some reason, when I change the URL using HTML instead of JavaScript (i.e. clicking on a `<a href="#/link">` vs `window.location = '#/link';`) I am running into abnormal behaviors.

Any general knowledge that may be the answer to this? I would post code but there's too much for debugging.

Answer (score 0):

i dont use to change the urls with 'window.location' nor with 'a href', maybe that causes your problem.
I use states in order to change the urls.

I use  **'ui.router'** into main module and inject **$stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider** into **config(function())**, after that  on the function body i put the states(the urls of my pages), and i call them from any place into the application

**1. main module with the states:**

```
       angular.module('MainApp')
         .config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) { //$stateProvider & $urlRouterProvider are from ui.router module                         
        .state('floorplan', {
            url:/floorplan/:param1/:param2/:param3',
            controller:'myCtrl1',
            templateUrl:'/assets/modules/part3/part3.html'                
            onEnter: function () {
            },
            onExit: function () {                   
            }
        })
        .state('seating', {
            url: '/seating',
            template: '<div>Seating is under construction</div>'
        })
        .state('event_details', {
            url: '/event/details',
            template: '<div>Event details is under construction</div>'
        })
        .state('reports', {
            url: '/reports',
            template: '<div>Reports is under construction</div>'
        })
        .state('part3', {
            url: '/part3/:activeEventId/:activeHallId/:activeHallVariant',
            controller: 'part3ctrl',
            templateUrl: '/assets/modules/part3/part3.html',
            onEnter: function () {

            },
            onExit: function () {
            }
        })
        .state('login', {
            url: '/login',
            controller: 'LoginCtrl',
            templateUrl: '/assets/modules/login/login.html',
            onEnter: function () {
            },
            onExit: function () {
            }
        });
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('floorplan'); //when no route found redirect to login
});
```

**2. here i call a state , in order to change the page**
  first of all you inject the '$state' into your controller and when you need to change url :

```
$state.go('floorplan', {
                 'param1': val1,
                 'param2': val2,
                 'param3': val3
        });
```

Hope helps good luck.